# backend node js with mongoDB, patch request does not update date type value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, serverside-javascript

I use node.js to build the backend and persist the data in MongoDB. When I do a patch request, I can change the values of all the fields of other types except for the one of date type.

This is the backend code for the patch request.

```
router.patch('/:id', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updatedBooking = await Booking.updateOne(
            {_id: req.params.id},
            {
                $set: {userEmail: req.body.userEmail},  
                $set: {shiftDate: req.body.shiftDate},
                $set: {isMorningShift: req.body.isMorningShift}
            }
        );
        res.json(updatedBooking);
    } catch (err) {
        res.send({message: err});
    }
});
```

This is the database scheme:

```
const BookingSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    userEmail:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    shiftDate:{
        type:Date,
        required:true
    },
    isMorningShift:{
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }
});
```

The objects in MongoDB look like this:

```
 {
    "_id": "61787183e67b6822180175f9",
    "userEmail": "admin2@parantion.nl",
    "isMorningShift": false,
    "__v": 0,
    "shiftDate": "2066-06-23T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: use `new Date(req.body.shiftDate)` and check if it works. You may be adding Date string in wrong format.

Comment: @AlokPrakash it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
$set: {shiftDate: req.body.shiftDate}
```

to

```
$set: {shiftDate: new Date(req.body.shiftDate)}
```

or

```
$set: {shiftDate: new Date()}  //for todays date in your local format
```

**This works:**
I tested this with express like so:

```
app.get('/updateOne', async (req, res) => {
     //get data through query params in url
     const id = req.query.id;
     const date = req.query.date;
     //connect to db and collection     
     //1 connect
     //2 set db and collection
     const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, { 
         useNewUrlParser: true, 
         useUnifiedTopology: true,
     });
     const collection = client.db("sample_airbnb").collection("listingsAndReviews");
    //update function for date field
    try {
        const updatedBooking = await collection.updateOne(
            {_id: id},
            {
                $set: {name: new Date(date)} //2066-06-23T00:00:00.000Z
            }
        );
        res.json(updatedBooking);
    } catch (err) {
        res.send({'message': err});
    }
})
```

Response:

```
{
    "acknowledged": true,
    "modifiedCount": 1,
    "upsertedId": null,
    "upsertedCount": 0,
    "matchedCount": 1
}
```

And updated data in Mongoscloud:

```
_id
:
"100009690"
name
:
2066-06-23T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

The I called the endpoint like so:
`http://localhost:5000/updateOne?id=100009690&date=2066-06-23T00:00:00.000Z` and you see it's the same date format you say you expect.

Can you update your OP and show us the exact format you are passing in?? DO a `console.log(req.body.shiftDate)` on line 7 just before you pass it. I suspect here is where the issue is.

Obviously I shouldn't add dates to names field but this is purely for a quick test.

If updating multiple fields I'd with:

```
//update function
    try {
        const updatedBooking = await collection.updateOne(
            {_id: id},
            { 
                $set: {
                    name: name, 
                    email: email, 
                    lastShift: new Date(date)
                }
            }
        );
        res.json(updatedBooking);
    } catch (err) {
        res.send({'message': err});
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: It should. I just tested this again and works as is. I guess you can pass in athe date format you expect and it executes fine. See my update

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple `$set`, update all the keys in one,

```
const updatedBooking = await Booking.updateOne(
            {_id: req.params.id},
            {
                $set: {
                       userEmail: req.body.userEmail,  
                       shiftDate: new Date(req.body.shiftDate),
                       isMorningShift: req.body.isMorningShift
               }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

@fractal397's answer will work fine. If you want a more cleaner code, you can use this.

```
const bookingId = req.params.id;
const payload =
   userEmail: req.body.userEmail,  
   shiftDate: new Date(req.body.shiftDate),
   isMorningShift: req.body.isMorningShift
}
const booking = await Booking.findByIdAndUpdate(bookingId, payload);
```

P.S. - After Mongoose 4.0, `new` value for findByIdAndUpdate has been changed to `false` by default. So in this operation, data will be updated in the database but it will return the old value `booking`. To get updated value in response too, you will have to do -

`const booking = await Booking.findByIdAndUpdate(bookingId, payload, { new : true });`